# How to select a column from a row-major array in sub-linear time?

Tags: c++, c

Lets say that I'm given a row major array.

```
int* a = (int *)malloc( 9 x 9 x sizeof(int));
```

Look at this as a 2D 9x9 array where a (row,column) index corresponds to [row * 9 + column]
Is there a way where I can select a single column from this array in sub-linear time?
Since the columns wont be contiguous, we cant do a direct memcpy like we do to get a single row.

The linear-time solution would be obvious I guess, but I'm hoping for some sub-linear solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Just so that I'm clear on my question. For copying individual rows, if you use memcpy, since the memory is contiguous, and if the array is large enough, it would copy block-by-block and not linearly iterate over each element, hence I said row-wise copy is sub-linear.

Comment: and by sublinear, I mean a solution faster than O(N) where N is the width of the square array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by *sublinear*. If you consider the 2D array as NxN size, then *sublinear* on *N* is **impossible**. To copy *N* elements you need to perform *N* copy operations, the copy will be *linear* on the number of elements being copied.

The comment about `memcpy` seem to indicate that you mistakenly believe that `memcpy` is *sublinear* on the number of elements being copied. It is not. The advantage of `memcpy` is that the *constant* hidden in the big-O notation is small, but the operation is linear on the size of the memory being copied.

The next question is whether the big-O analysis actually makes sense. If your array is 9x9, then the effect hidden in the constant of the big-O notation can be more important than the complexity.

Comment: doesn't memcpy copy a block at a time, which makes it faster than linearly copying each element.

Comment: @nicko, copying a block is a linear operation also. Regardless, O(n/blocksize) is still O(n).

Comment: If the block-size is sqrt(N), wouldn't the operation become O(N^1/2)?

Comment: @nicko: It is linear on the size of the block, which is in turn proportional on the number of elements. You need to be careful with what the asymptotic notation means. It can be stated that copying 1Gb of data is a constant time operation (with a huge constant) while copying the elements of an array is linear on the size of the array, which holds true even for arrays of 10 elements. The question is what your dimension N represents.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer. Insightful. N is the width of the square array, but I think I got the general pitfall that my reasoning had.

Comment: @nicko: If you consider N as the number of elements in the array, then you can get a O( sqrt(N) ) algorithm that just copies one by one each element in the column. But that is what I am calling *linear* in the answer, note that I stated the dimensions of the array as being N*N. If your N' represents the whole array then your O( sqrt(N') ) algorithm is just O( N ) with my choice of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean but consider:

```
 const size_t x_sz=9;
 size_t x=3, y=6; //or which ever element you wish to access
 int value=a[Y*x_sz+x];
```

this will be a constant time O(1) expression. It must calculate the offset and load the value.

to iterate through every value in a column:

```
 const size_t x_sz=9, y_sz=9;
 size_t x=3; //or which ever column you wish to access

 for(size_t y=0; y!=y_sz; ++y){
     int value=a[Y*x_sz+x];
     //value is current column value
 }
```

again each iteration is constant time, the whole iteration sequence is therefore O(n) (linear), note that it would still be linear if it was contiguous.